# What is the role of the last argument ( $uniqueId ) in PHP Gearman's doNormal()?

Tags: php, process, jobs, worker, gearman

In PHP's documentation ( http://php.net/manual/en/gearmanclient.donormal.php ) you can see the last attribute to be a Unique Identifier for the task.

1. How do you find a task based on the Unique Identifier ?
2. Why use $unique and not $job_handler from jobStatus()
   ( http://php.net/manual/en/gearmanclient.jobstatus.php ) ?

Comment: 1 scroll down the page : "`unique` A unique ID used to identify a particular task." it's function is to identify the task you're creating. probably used for killing said task if need be.

Comment: Ok, I've read that, but can you answer my two questions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you cannot find a task based on the Unique Identifier.